# Exchange Oauth Request Token for Access Token fails Google API

Tags: python, oauth, google-api

I am having trouble exchanging my Oauth request token for an Access Token. My Python application successfully asks for a Request Token and then redirects to the Google login page asking to grant access to my website. When I grant access I retrieve a 200 status code but exchanging this authorized request token for an access token gives me a 'The token is invalid' message.

The Google Oauth documentation says: "Google redirects with token and verifier regardless of whether the token has been authorized." so it seems that authorizing the request token fails but then I am not sure how I should get an authorized request token. Any suggestions?

Comment: I have to dig it up and I'll post it soon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you're exchanging for the access token, the oauth_verifier parameter is required. If you don't provide that parameter, then google will tell you that the token is invalid.